# How to correctly model human eye sight with OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

Consider I know the real world coordinates of a small display (e.g. a smartphone), so four points (x,y,z) describing the four corners and I know the position of a human facing the device, so I know the (x,y,z) coordinates of the human's eyes as well as head orientation.
I now want to want to render a scene in which the device is perceived as it is perceived by the human at the given position, i.e. the OpenGL camera should simulate the human eyes.

I face several problems:

- FoV: I read several threads coming from game development (FPS). Most of them suggest values between 45° and 90° as it would look realistic. I'm unsure whether "look realistic" is enough for my use case  - is there anything more precise I could use instead of hoping that it "looks realistic"?
- How to correctly place the quad in the virtual coordinates? Consider my device is 10x10 cm large and I know that it should be 40 cm in front of my eyes, 30 cm below the direct line of sight and translated 20 cm to the left. I render the quad in size 2x2 units, but I'm pretty sure that it is not as easy as saying 1 unit corresponds to 5 cm - or is it?

Comment: "look realistic" is the standard for CG

Comment: You can achieve the effect you want be using an asymmetric view frustum. Basically. You need the position of the eye relative to the 4 corner points of the display, and construct a frustum constrained by the 4 rays from the eye point to the camera. TO get this really right, you need a stereoscopic display and a frustum per eye. In the monoscopic case, best you can do is usinng ehe center point between both eyes.